# Conversion of Function Pointer Non-Type Template Parameter to Type Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates

The following example code compiles under gcc and works as I would hope.  It allows me to instantiate an object with a function definition as a template parameter, but then the class is able to use the different types in the function as if they were passed individually as type template parameters.

```
template<class FuncSignature> class Obj;

template<class Type1, class Type2> class Obj<Type1 (Type2)>
{
public:
  Type1 var1;
  Type2 var2;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Obj<char (int)> A;
  A.var1 = 'a';
  A.var2 = 3;
}
```

Even though it seems to work, I'm not sure what this code is doing.  Why does this code work and does it conform to the C++ standard?

Comment: yes, its legal,
when unsure, i try http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ to check compliance.  it works because of partial template specialization.

Comment: With meta programming, you can actually extract most information about a function type (here `char(int)`) using the Boost FunctionTypes library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/index.html It might be hardcode, but it's an interesting read :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why shouldn't it work? The instantiation matches the specialization, which extracts the component types (`char` and `int`) of the compound type (a function, `char(int)`) as `Type1` and `Type2`.

By the way, you don't have a non-type template parameter. A function type is a type. If you had a non-type template parameter, then it would look like this:

```
template <char(int)>
struct X {};

char foobar(int);

int main()
{
    X<foobar> x;
}
```

Or fully templated:

```
template <class R, class A, R(A)>
//                          ^^^^
//                      non-type parameter
struct X {};

char foobar(int);

int main()
{
    X<char, int, foobar> x;
//               ^^^^^^
//   a specific function, not type
}
```

Comment: I sense source of confusion here: "A function is a type." that's not really true. Only if you know these things, you can deduce what this sentence means. To reduce source of confusion, better accurately say "A function type is a type.". Equally, an integer is not a type. But an integer type is. The same way, the questioner probably confused himself by saying "it allows me to instantiate an object with a function definition as a template parameter" - that statement doesn't make sense in any way.

Comment: I see I was confused in many ways.  One being I didn't know char (int) was a type known as a function type. I also didn't realize there was a template specialization occurring based on this function type.  I have never seen a template specialization that has a non-empty template list.  Are there cases other than specializing to a function type where that may happen?

Comment: @user334066: this is called partial specialization, ie you "specialize" the template but there are still template parameters (and sometimes more than there were previously as in your case).

Answer (score 3):

This question is a misnomer because `FuncSignature` is not a non-type template parameter.

However, the code given works by specializing the (general) type `FuncSignature` for unary function types (`Type1 (Type2)` is a function type, given types `Type1` and `Type2`).

So the first line defines a general template, the next group of lines specializes it for the type form `Type1 (Type2)`, which are parameterized on two types, hence the specialization has a non-empty template parameter list, and the `main` instantiates the template for the concrete type `char (int)` (a function taking an `int` and returning a `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This code conforms the standard :)

In the case of:

```
Obj<char (int)>
```

`Type1` is `char` and `Type2` is `int`. For that reason `Obj::var1` is member variable of type `char` and `Obj::var2` is member variable of type `int`.